# mysql joining table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am new with joining tables.

```
ClassList
========================
ID      Level
1       2
2       2
3       4
4       1
5       3
6       7

BoysList
========================
ID      Name        Age
1       Alex        13
2       Arnold      16
3       Barny       15

GirlsList
========================
ID      Name        Age
4       Arnie       12
5       Martha      17
6       Beth        15
```

I was able to join two tables. But, what if, in this situation, you have to combine first the two tables (BoysList and GirlsList) and then join it with ClassList.

The Resultset would be:

```
Result
================================================
ID      Name
4       Arnie           
6       Beth        
5       Martha      
1       Alex    
2       Arnold  
3       Barny
```

order of the result would be list of boys girls first, name ASC. How do accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the first thing you will do is to `UNION` the BoysList and GirlsList then `INNER JOIN` it with ClassList

```
SELECT  iStudentList.`ID`,
    iStudentList.`Name`,
    iStudentList.`Age`,
    ClassList.`iOrder`
FROM
ClassList INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Age`, "A" as iOrder FROM BoyssList
        UNION
     SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Age`, "B" as iOrder FROM GirlsList) as iStudentList
ON ClassList.`ID` = iStudentList.`ID`
ORDER BY ClassList.`iOrder` DESC, iStudentList.`Name` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use union all
(hope this query isn't error)

`select cl.id, bl.name

from ClassList cl, BoysList bl

where cl.id = bl.id

order by bl.name

union all

select cl.id, gl.name

from ClassList cl, GirlsList gl

where cl.id = gl.id

order by cl.name`

Revised query:

`select cl.id, bl.name, 'A' as ket

from boyList bl, classList cl

where bl.id = cl.id

union all

select cl.id, gl.name, 'B' as ket

from girlList gl, classList cl

where gl.id = cl.id

order by ket desc, name`

Comment: I'm sorry, I've try my code above and get error code... I've revised it become: select cl.id, bl.name, 'A' as ket
from boyList bl, classList cl
where bl.id = cl.id
union all
select cl.id, gl.name, 'B' as ket
from girlList gl, classList cl
where gl.id = cl.id
order by ket desc, name
and it's work... and thanks johntotetwoo

Answer (score 1):

Besides `UNION`, you can use `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    cl.ID                         AS ID
  , COALESCE(b.`Name`, g.`Name`)  AS Name
  , COALESCE(b.Age, g.Age)        AS Age
  , cl.`Level`                    AS Level
FROM
      ClassList AS cl
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      BoysList AS b
          ON b.ID = cl.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      GirlsList AS g
          ON g.ID = cl.ID
```